# Хлебные крошки не правильно отображают пути. WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-плагины, breadcrumbs

Использую хлебные крошки Dimox Breadcrumbs

Вот что выводит

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Страницы расположены так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно чтобы отображалось "Главная - О компании"

Как можно эту ошибку исправить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Честно говоря, я бы Вам советовал установить Breadcrumbs NavXT и не морочить себе голову багфиксами чужого кода (это конечно лично моё субъективное мнение и я его никому не навязываю). Но давайте разберемся что здесь происходит.

Смотрим на проверку в самом начале:

```
if ( $show_home_link ) {
  $position += 1;
  echo $home_link;
}
```

Если у Вас опция `$show_home_link = 1;`, то показывается ссылка на главную страницу, всегда, но не учтен случай, когда хлебные крошки выводятся на дочерней странице главной страницы, вот и получается что у нас присутствует главная страница 2 раза. Выводится `Главная` -> `Родительская страница текущей (в Вашем случае она и есть главная)` -> `Текущая страница`.

Учтите, что я могу не все учесть и успеть протестировать, но в Вашем случае это должно сработать. Для того чтобы устранить данную проблему, мы можем получить ID главной страницы и не показывать её второй раз в хлебных крошках. Для этого модифицируем код хлебных крошек таким образом:

```
...
// Находим то место, где выводятся хлебные крошки для дочерней страницы
} elseif ( is_page() && $parent_id ) {
  $parents = get_post_ancestors( get_the_ID() );
  // Получаем ID главной страницы.
  $home_page_ID = get_option( 'page_on_front' );

  foreach ( array_reverse( $parents ) as $pageID ) {
    // И добавляем нашу строку, где проверяем, если ID родительской страницы == ID домашней страницы, то мы просто переходим к следующей итерации цикла.
    if ( $home_page_ID == $pageID ) continue;
    $position += 1;
    if ( $position > 1 ) echo $sep;
    echo sprintf( $link, get_page_link( $pageID ), get_the_title( $pageID ), $position );

  }
  if ( $show_current ) echo $sep . $before . get_the_title() . $after;
  elseif ( $show_last_sep ) echo $sep;
}
...
```

Comment: Спасибо! Сработало!!!